# How do i change package and app name in Compose Multiplatform?

Tags: android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-multiplatform

I created a compose multiplatform project using [Jetbrains template](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-multiplatform-ios-android-template) with package name as `com.myapplication` and app name as `My Application` by default. Now i'm not sure how to change both package and app name. I tried top answers in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/rename-package-in-android-studio) but none of them working for KMM project.

Answer (score 2):

This is the best way I could find by trial and error. Let me know if a better method exists.

- Replace all occurrences of `com.myapplication.MyApplication` with your intended package name like this.
  [image: replace with your package name]
- Then rename the folder `myapplication`(located in `androidApp/src/androidMain/`) to your package middle name.
  [image]
- In `build.gradle.kts` (from `shared` module) change the namespace value and add `binaryOption("bundleId", "com.company.AppName")` in `cocoapods { ... framework { ...`.

You don't need to change names in `BuildConfig` or other folders under `build` folder.